# Steam client not launching in Xubuntu recently upgraded to Disco Dingo from Cosmic Cuttlefish

Tags: xubuntu, steam, 19.04

The title says it all
This is the terminal output:

```
camilo@camilo-S400CA:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 19.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
camilo@camilo-S400CA:~$
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably already running under that user. Perhaps Big-Picture mode minimized on a different workspace?

`ps wx | grep steam` should show you any running instances:

[image]